# Reduce each node of tree into list of tips of tree

Tags: javascript, node.js, tree

Here is the runnable code:
https://gist.github.com/the1mills/61d53438a3dce1da32640d3e05a611a6

(I couldn't figure out how to load the async library using JSBin or RequireBin online, maybe someone knows how to do that).

I have this tree structure:

```
const animals = {
  canines: {
    dogs: {
      poodle: {
        val: true
      }
    },
    fox:{
      val: true
    },
    wolf: {
      northwestern:{
        val: true
      },
      arctic: {
        val: true
      }
    },
    raccoon:{
      val: true
    }
  },
  porpoises: {
    vaquita:{
      val: true
    },
    harbor: {
      val: true
    }
  },

};
```

For each node in the tree, I want to get a description of each branch from that node, reducing the branch keys into one key, so that I get:

```
  // canines node: 
[{"Dogs.Poodle": true}, {"Fox":true}, {"Wolf.Northwestern":true}, {"Wolf.Arctic":true}, {"Raccoon" : true}]

   // porpoisies node: 
[{"Vaquita": true}, {"Harbor":true}]

   // and at the animals node:
 [{"Canines.Dogs.Poodle": true}, {"Canines.Fox":true}, {"Canines.Wolf.Northwestern":true}, {"Canines.Wolf.Arctic":true}, {"Canines.Raccoon" : true}, {"Porpoises.Vaquita": true}, {"Porpoises.Harbor":true}]
```

I have this code, but I can't figure out what's wrong with it. I need to keep it asynchronous because I will be doing so I/O, but we can simulate that with process.nextTick for the purposes of the question.

```
const uppercaseFirstChar = s => {
  return s.slice(0,1).toUpperCase() + s.slice(1).toLowerCase();
};


const loop = (v, list, cb) => {

  const results = [];

  async.eachLimit(Object.keys(v), 3, (k, cb) => {

    const sub = v[k];

    if (sub && typeof sub === 'object') {

      for (let l of list) {
        l.push({
          key: k
        });
      }

      return loop(sub, list.concat([results]), err => {

        const path = results.reduce((a, b) => {
          return {
            val: a.val,
            key: uppercaseFirstChar(a.key) + '.' + uppercaseFirstChar(b.key)
          }
        });

        console.log({path});

        cb(err);
      });
    }

    for (let l of list) {
      l.push({
        val: sub,
        key: k
      });
    }

    process.nextTick(cb);


  }, cb);

};

const list = [];

loop(animals, list, (err, val) => {
  console.log(err, val);
});
```

In my code, for each node I am looking the tree paths, and I am getting some wild results, I cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the code condenses/collapses itself, you usually know you're on the right track:

```
const loop = (v, cb) => {

  const results = [];

  async.eachLimit(Object.keys(v), 3, (k, cb) => {

    const sub = v[k];

    if (sub && typeof sub === 'object') {

      return loop(sub, (err, values) => {

        for(let v of values){
          results.push(k + v);
        }

        cb(err);
      });
    }


    results.push(k);
    process.nextTick(cb);


  }, err => {
     cb(err, results);
  });

};


loop(animals, (err, val) => {
  console.log(err, val);
});
```

the problem with my code above was that object references in the array were being shared by all branches, so each branch was getting overpopulated, if you will.